# NLTK perceptron tagger "TypeError: 'LazySubsequence' object does not support item assignment"

Tags: classification, nltk, anaconda, python-3.5, perceptron

I would like to try and use the `PerceptronTagger` in the `nltk` package for Python 3.5, But I am getting the error `TypeError: 'LazySubsequence' object does not support item assignment`

I would like to train it with data from the brown corpus with the `universal` tagset.

Here is the code I am running when I have the issue.

```
import nltk,math
tagged_sentences = nltk.corpus.brown.tagged_sents(categories='news',tagset='universal')
i = math.floor(len(tagged_sentences)*0.2)
testing_sentences = tagged_sentences[0:i]
training_sentences = tagged_sentences[i:]
perceptron_tagger = nltk.tag.perceptron.PerceptronTagger(load=False)
perceptron_tagger.train(training_sentences)
```

It won't train correctly, and gives the following stack trace.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-61332d63d2c3> in <module>()
      1 perceptron_tagger = nltk.tag.perceptron.PerceptronTagger(load=False)
----> 2 perceptron_tagger.train(training_sentences)

/home/nathan/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nltk/tag/perceptron.py in train(self, sentences, save_loc, nr_iter)
    192                     c += guess == tags[i]
    193                     n += 1
--> 194             random.shuffle(sentences)
    195             logging.info("Iter {0}: {1}/{2}={3}".format(iter_, c, n, _pc(c, n)))
    196         self.model.average_weights()

/home/nathan/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/random.py in shuffle(self, x, random)
    270                 # pick an element in x[:i+1] with which to exchange x[i]
    271                 j = randbelow(i+1)
--> 272                 x[i], x[j] = x[j], x[i]
    273         else:
    274             _int = int

TypeError: 'LazySubsequence' object does not support item assignment
```

It seems to be coming from the `shuffle` function in the `random` module but that doesn't really seem right.

Is there something else that could cause the problem? 
Has someone had this issue?

I am running this on Ubuntu 16.04.1 with Anaconda Python 3.5. The `nltk` version is `3.2.1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NLTK has a lot of custom "lazy" types, which should ease mangling of large bodies of data, such as annotated corpora. They behave like the standard lists, tuples, dicts etc. in many ways, but avoid occupying too much memory unnecessarily.

One instance of this is the `LazySubsequence`, which is the result of the slice expression `tagged_sentences[i:]`. If `tagged_sentences` was a normal list, the division of the data into test/training would create an entire copy of the data. Instead, this `LazySubsequence` is a *view* to parts of the original sequence.

While the memory benefits of this are a probably a good thing, the problem here is that this view is read-only.
Apparently the `PerceptronTagger` would like to shuffle its input data in-place, which is not allowed – hence the exception.

A quick (but maybe not the most elegant) solution is to provide the tagger with a copy of the data:

```
perceptron_tagger.train(tuple(training_sentences))
```

You might have to do the same thing with the test data.

Comment: Looks like you wrote an answer while I was writing mine. I came to the same conclusion, so I'll mark yours as correct since I appreciate the effort.

Comment: It's good you found the solution yourself! These NLTK containers can be very tricky to work with, sometimes...

Answer (score 5):

## Debugging

Doing some `grep`ing in the `nltk` source code found the answer.

In the file `site-packages/nltk/util.py` the class is declared.

```
class LazySubsequence(AbstractLazySequence):
    """                                                                                                                                                                  
    A subsequence produced by slicing a lazy sequence.  This slice                                                                                                       
    keeps a reference to its source sequence, and generates its values                                                                                                   
    by looking them up in the source sequence.                                                                                                                           
    """
```

After another quick test from the interpreter I see the following details about the `type()` of the `tagged_sentences`

```
>>> import nltk
>>> tagged_sentences = nltk.corpus.brown.tagged_sents(categories='news',tagset='universal')
>>> type(tagged_sentences)
<class 'nltk.corpus.reader.util.ConcatenatedCorpusView'>
```

I see in the file `site-packages/nltk/corpus/reader/util.py`

```
class ConcatenatedCorpusView(AbstractLazySequence):
    """                                                                                                                                                                  
    A 'view' of a corpus file that joins together one or more                                                                                                            
    ``StreamBackedCorpusViews<StreamBackedCorpusView>``.  At most                                                                                                        
    one file handle is left open at any time.                                                                                                                            
    """
```

A final test with the `random` package proves the problem exists in the way I am creating the `tagged_sentences`

```
>>> import random
>>> random.shuffle(training_sentences)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-0b03f0366949> in <module>()
      1 import random
----> 2 random.shuffle(training_sentences)
      3 
      4 
      5 

/home/nathan/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/random.py in shuffle(self, x, random)
    270                 # pick an element in x[:i+1] with which to exchange x[i]
    271                 j = randbelow(i+1)
--> 272                 x[i], x[j] = x[j], x[i]
    273         else:
    274             _int = int

TypeError: 'LazySubsequence' object does not support item assignment
```

## Solution

To work around the error, just explicitly create a list of the sentences from the `nltk.corpus.brown` package then `random` can shuffle the data properly.

```
import nltk,math
# explicitly make list, then LazySequence will traverse all items
tagged_sentences = [sentence for sentence in nltk.corpus.brown.tagged_sents(categories='news',tagset='universal')]
i = math.floor(len(tagged_sentences)*0.2)
testing_sentences = tagged_sentences[0:i]
training_sentences = tagged_sentences[i:]
perceptron_tagger = nltk.tag.perceptron.PerceptronTagger(load=False)
perceptron_tagger.train(training_sentences)
# no error, yea!
```

Now the tagging works as desired.

```
>>> perceptron_tagger_preds = []
>>> for test_sentence in testing_sentences:
...    perceptron_tagger_preds.append(perceptron_tagger.tag([word for word,_ in test_sentence]))
>>> print(perceptron_tagger_preds[676])
[('Formula', 'NOUN'), ('is', 'VERB'), ('due', 'ADJ'), ('this', 'DET'), ('week', 'NOUN')]
```